# Adding Navigation to a HyperLink C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to add a navigation process to another page when clicking on a certain hyperlink.

```
<DataGridHyperlinkColumn x:Name="Hyperlink" Header="Hyperlink"  ContentBinding="{Binding Name}"
```

There is no Click function for the `DataGridHyperLinkColumn`. How can I implement an "On click function" then?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You would typically bind an URI to the `DataGridHyperlinkColumn`:

```xml
<DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="Hyperlink" 
                         Binding="{Binding NavigationDestinationUri}"
                         ContentBinding="{Binding Name}" />
```

The `DataGridHyperlinkColumn` will create a `Hyperlink` internally. Clicking this `Hyperlink` raises the `Hyperlink.RequestNavigate` and `Hyperlink.Click` routed events that are handled by a parent navigation host (e.g. `Frame`).
For this reason, any parent of the `DataGridHyperlinkColumn` can also handle the `Hyperlink.Click` and `Hyperlink.RequestNavigate` routed events.

If you want to use an `ICommand` or click event handler you would have to use a `DataGridTemplateColumn` and add a `Hyperlink` to the cell template:

```xml
<DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="Hyperlink">
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
   
      <!-- Wrap it into a TextBlock to make it clickable without pressing Ctrl -->
      <TextBlock>
        <Hyperlink Command="{Binding NavigationCommand}"
                   Click="OnHyperlinkClicked" />  
      </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```